# CA basic animation in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cabasicanimation

i need to rotate and move same image simultaneously with CA BASIC ANIMATION, is there any way out for this in iphone sdk

any help will be highly appreciated

---

This is My Code

```
 imgview = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:imagenumber];
 CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
 anim.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(160 + x_movefrom, 240 + y_movefrom)];
 anim.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(160 + x_moveto, 240 + y_moveto)];
 anim.duration   = 2;
 anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

 //imgview = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:imagenumber];

CABasicAnimation *opacityAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"alpha"];
opacityAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
opacityAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
opacityAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:opacityAnim,anim, nil];
animGroup.duration = 2;
animGroup.delegate = self;
animGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[imgview.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877584/rotate-and-translate-uiimageview-off-and-on-screen) a sample code to do that.

The key is creating two `CABasicAnimation` and then group them in a `CAAnimationGroup`.

REMAR ON YOUR CODE:

to animate the opacity, try to use this:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
```

instead of

```
CABasicAnimation *opacityAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"alpha"];
```

Comment: thanks you for your quick response, i am doing the same, but only opacity is not working. i have set effect like fade out